# How do I get the Video Id from the URL? (DailyMotion)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Example:

```
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4xvnz_the-funny-crash-compilation_fun
```

How do I get `x4xvnz`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`basename` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to get the last part of the URL and then [`strtok` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to get the ID (all characters up to the first `_`):

```
$id = strtok(basename($url), '_');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/video\/([^_]+)/
```

should do the trick. This grabs in the first capture all text after `video/` up till the first  `_`.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('#<object[^>]+>.+?http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/video/([A-Za-z0-9]+).+?</object>#s', $dailymotionurl, $matches);

        // Dailymotion url
        if(!isset($matches[1])) {
            preg_match('#http://www.dailymotion.com/video/([A-Za-z0-9]+)#s', $dailymotionurl, $matches);
        }

        // Dailymotion iframe
        if(!isset($matches[1])) {
            preg_match('#http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/([A-Za-z0-9]+)#s', $dailymotionurl, $matches);
        }
 $id =  $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
function getDailyMotionId($url)
{

    if (preg_match('!^.+dailymotion\.com/(video|hub)/([^_]+)[^#]*(#video=([^_&]+))?|(dai\.ly/([^_]+))!', $url, $m)) {
        if (isset($m[6])) {
            return $m[6];
        }
        if (isset($m[4])) {
            return $m[4];
        }
        return $m[2];
    }
    return false;
}
```

It can handle various urls:

```
$dailymotion = [
    'http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2jvvep_coup-incroyable-pendant-un-match-de-ping-pong_tv',
    'http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2jvvep_rates-of-exchange-like-a-renegade_music',
    'http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2jvvep',
    'http://www.dailymotion.com/hub/x2jvvep_Galatasaray',
    'http://www.dailymotion.com/hub/x2jvvep_Galatasaray#video=x2jvvep',
    'http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2jvvep_hakan-yukur-klip_sport',
    'http://dai.ly/x2jvvep',
];
```

Check out my github (https://github.com/lingtalfi/video-ids-and-thumbnails/blob/master/testvideo.php), I provide functions to get ids (and also thumbnails) from youtube, vimeo and dailymotion.

Comment: this function is very nice. Let me however add a slight update : it's failing on this case :
`https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7bm45u?playlist=x6ffqw`
to handle it, just change `([^_]+)` by `([^_?]+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$output = parse_url("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4xvnz_the-funny-crash-compilation_fun");

// The part you want
$url= $output['path'];
$parts = explode('/',$url);
$parts = explode('_',$parts[2]);

echo $parts[0];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php